# Best program for keeping track of Time (motor racing)

Tags: time, alarm

**Short Version:**

Program to:

- control racing (cars) laptimes (it must not reset)
- be able to use as a chronometer
- b able to use as a reverse chronometer (start in X min:secs end in 00:00)

**Long Version:**

I need a program to control time, I need the time to go forth and back (for me to choose)
and I insert the starting time.

I also need a program to control lap times.

If anyone know any program for these stuff (racing stuff), I would apreciate it, even if there only are paid solution, I still would like to take a look at them (I staring to make a program in python and it could be good for inspiration)

After some search, I could only find this:
It's a simple clock in python TKinter..... if anyone has anything more advanced... (easier to change :) )

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

from Tkinter import *
import time

class StopWatch(Frame):  
    """ Implements a stop watch frame widget. """                                                                
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):        
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self._start = 0.0        
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0
        self._running = 0
        self.timestr = StringVar()               
        self.makeWidgets()      

    def makeWidgets(self):                         
        """ Make the time label. """
        l = Label(self, textvariable=self.timestr)
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        l.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=2, padx=2)                      
    
    def _update(self): 
        """ Update the label with elapsed time. """
        self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        self._timer = self.after(50, self._update)
    
    def _setTime(self, elap):
        """ Set the time string to Minutes:Seconds:Hundreths """
        minutes = int(elap/60)
        seconds = int(elap - minutes*60.0)
        hseconds = int((elap - minutes*60.0 - seconds)*100)                
        self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds, hseconds))
        
    def Start(self):                                                     
        """ Start the stopwatch, ignore if running. """
        if not self._running:            
            self._start = time.time() - self._elapsedtime
            self._update()
            self._running = 1        
    
    def Stop(self):                                    
        """ Stop the stopwatch, ignore if stopped. """
        if self._running:
            self.after_cancel(self._timer)            
            self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start    
            self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
            self._running = 0
    
    def Reset(self):                                  
        """ Reset the stopwatch. """
        self._start = time.time()         
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0    
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        
        
def main():
    root = Tk()
    sw = StopWatch(root)
    sw.pack(side=TOP)
    
    Button(root, text='Start', command=sw.Start).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Stop', command=sw.Stop).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Reset', command=sw.Reset).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).pack(side=LEFT)
    
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Could you explain some more what you are looking for ? For me it reads like science-fiction stuff.

Comment: I agree @harrymc, just "import tardis" and time travel away. How are you reading in the information from the chronometer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with a packaged solution, you should try some of the apps:

- for your android phone: http://www.bestandroidappsreview.com/2010/05/top-android-app-ultimate-stopwatch.html
- for your iphone: http://www.apple.com/webapps/utilities/stopwatch_benku.html which is free, but if you want a more powerful stopwatch you should try LAPZERO app (see demo http://www.lapzero.com/v4/)
- for your windows mobile phone: http://www.ageye.de/index.php?s=grace/about
- or find one for your desktop computer platform/system on google

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is a milliseconds accurate stop watch and lap timer.

Not that I have tried it but heres one I found on google http://www.xnotestopwatch.com/

I wish I could vote, cause that `import tardis` crack was a good one. :P